# ASP.Net: Adding client side onClick to a HyperlinkField in GridView

Tags: asp.net, gridview, c#-3.0

I have an existing GridView which contains the field "partner name". It is sortable by partner name.
Now I need to change the Partner Name field and in some condition make it clickable and alert() something.

The existing code is:

```
  <asp:GridView ID="gridViewAdjustments" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" AllowSorting="True" OnSorting="gridView_Sorting" OnRowDataBound="OnRowDataBoundAdjustments" EnableViewState="true">
         <asp:BoundField DataField="PartnerName" HeaderText="Name" SortExpression="PartnerName"/>
```

I've added the column:

```
<asp:hyperlinkfield  datatextfield="PartnerName" SortExpression="PartnerName" headertext="Name" ItemStyle-CssClass="text2"/>
```

which enables me to control the CSS and sort. However, I can't find how to add a client side javascript function to it.
  I found that adding :

```
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Edit">                                     
<ItemTemplate>
      <a id="lnk" runat="server">Edit</a>
```

enable me to access "lnk" by id and add to its attributes. However, I lose the Sort ability.

What's the correct solution in this case?
Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The solution I found was using asp:TemplateField this way, without losing the Sorting ability and using the datatextfield using Eval:

```
 <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Name" SortExpression="PartnerName">
<ItemTemplate>
        <a onclick="javascript:alert('ok')" href="http://<%#Eval("PartnerName")%>"><%#Eval("PartnerName")%></a>
</ItemTemplate></asp:TemplateField>
```

Answer (score 6):

Handle the `RowDataBound` event. In the event handler...

```
private void CustomersGridView_RowDataBound(Object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
   e.Row.Cells[0].Controls[0].Attributes.Add("onclick", "alert(‘An alert’);")
}
```

You might need to change `Controls[0]` to `Controls[1]`.

Comment: The error when defining an ID is: "Id attribute is invalid for tags that are not inherited from Control".

Comment: thanks - but still you can't give the asp:hyperlinkfield an ID... I see your point though.

Comment: Yes, I forgot to remove that bit.

Answer (score 3):

The ClientId generated looks quite different from ID but it always ends with ID. We can not use ID in Javascript or Jquery , so we can do as below:

```
 <asp:TemplateField  SortExpression="partnername" HeaderText="Partner">
    <ItemTemplate>
      <asp:HyperLink ID="kkx" Text='<%#Eval("partnername")%>'  NavigateUrl="# runat="server">
      </asp:HyperLink>
    </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
```

Then in Jquery we can do:

```
$(function() {
         $("#GridView1 a[id$=kkx]").bind('click', function() {
             alert('hi');
          });
      });
```

Answer (score 0):

jQuery. Simple one-liners and [unobtrusive](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript):

```
$('A.text2').click(function() {
    alert('ok');
});
```