# Error in OnClientClick in C#?

Tags: asp.net, gridview, hyperlink, webforms

I want a popup to be populated to user before deleting the record 
I have tried **OnClientClick** and **class** to handle it with JavaScript/jQuery but with no success

**ERROR**

```
Type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.HyperLinkField' does not have a public property named 'OnClientClick'.
```

**Control**

```
 <asp:HyperLinkField  OnClientClick="return confirm('Are you sure you would like to delete the selected landing page?')" datanavigateurlfields="id"    datanavigateurlformatstring="ViewLandingPages.aspx?id={0}&delete=yes"   HeaderText="Delete"  Text="Delete" />
```

**EDIT :** also tried adding a  **class** (for handling it with jquery ) but with no success

Comment: you wont to delete your record when you click on that hyperlink am i right ? if yes then i will give your another solution..

Comment: Take a look here for the solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2938224/asp-net-adding-client-side-onclick-to-a-hyperlinkfield-in-gridview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a template field solve my problem  ;)

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Delete" ShowHeader="False">
  <ItemTemplate>
     <a onclick="return confirm('Are you sure to delete a record?')" href="ViewLandingPages.aspx?delete=yes&id=<%# Eval("id") %>">Delete</a>
   </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Answer (score 2):

Note that it doesn't have an `OnClientClick` event [declared in its members](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.hyperlinkfield.aspx).

Try setting the `NavigateUrl` property like this:

```
NavigateUrl='<%# "javascript:return confirm('Are you sure you would like to delete the selected landing page?')" %>'
```

### Update

Try also setting the `DataNavigateUrlFormatString` like this:

```
DataNavigateUrlFormatString="{0}"
```

Comment: @Champ - now that's a different question. Next time put a bit more effort into your question :)

Comment: Much better @Champ, I knew exactly what you were trying to do from the question but I wanted to get you into the habit of working just as hard as those answering the question. Thanks! Take care my friend!

Comment: not working `Literal content ('<asp:HyperLinkField  datanavigateurlfields="id" 
                    NavigateUrl='') is not allowed within a 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataControlFieldCollection'.
`

Answer (score 2):

You can use  `<asp:Button/>`, `<asp:LinkButton/>` or `<asp:ImageButton/>` to handle click event at client and server side.

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
    <Columns>
       <!--- Other columns/Fields -->
        <asp:TemplateField>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:LinkButton 
                    ID="LinkButton1" 
                    runat="server" 
                    OnClientClick='return confirm("Are you sure to delete a record?")'
                    CommandName="Delete">Delete</asp:LinkButton>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Comment: how to pass the id of record to be deleated

Answer (score 0):

In my project i do like this i show a div for confirmation like this it's below

```
<div id="dvDeleteCategory" title="Delete Category">
    <h5>
        Are you sure you wont to delete this category !!!</h5>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {       
        $(".lnkDelete").button();
        $("#dvDeleteCategory").dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
            width: 400,
            modal: true,
            resizable: false,
            height: 250
        });

        $(".lnkDelete").click(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var trargeturl = $(this).attr('href');
            $("#dvDeleteCategory").dialog({
                buttons: {
                    "Delete": function () {
                        window.location.href = trargeturl;
                    },
                    "Cancle": function () {
                        $(this).dialog('close');
                    }
                }
            });
            $("#dvDeleteCategory").dialog('open');
        });
    });
</script>
```

i think this will help you ..