# How to open popup window with HyperLinkField in Gridwiev?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, hyperlink

I have a gridview and include lots of HyperLinkField

```
<asp:GridView ID="gv" AllowSelecting="true" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CssClass="class" EnableModelValidation="True" Width="100%"
 AllowPaging="True" PageSize="21"   OnRowDataBound="a_RowDataBound"  >
<Columns>

<asp:HyperLinkField  DataNavigateUrlFields="" DataTextField="_a" HeaderText="Invoice">
<HeaderStyle BackColor="#F0F1F3" ForeColor="black"  />
<ItemStyle ForeColor="Navy" HorizontalAlign="left" />
</asp:HyperLinkField> 

 </Columns>
<PagerStyle ForeColor="#3333CC" />
</asp:GridView>
```

I have a gridwiev with created HyperLinkField and I want to open popup when the click  `HyperLinkField`row.
I cannot add `OnClick` method in HyperLinkField . So What can I do? I can accept any alternative way

Comment: You can try target=_blank <asp:HyperLinkField  DataNavigateUrlFields="" DataTextField="_a" HeaderText="Invoice" Target="_blank"/>

Comment: duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2938224/asp-net-adding-client-side-onclick-to-a-hyperlinkfield-in-gridview